# POST -ing data with Laravel 4's resourceful controller does not work (store method) but works using index (GET) method. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: rest, laravel, controller

Hi I have a resource controller in **Laravel 4**. It has all the default methods generated by artisan's controller:make.

Models etc are in place.

User clicks on a link in a view that does a **URL::route** to a named route pointing at a  controller action. It points to the 'store()' method in the controller, which is meant to be a POST method.

I write my code in the 'store()' method to handle this request. It uses eloquent to insert data into db. It returns a plain text response with HTTP code 200.

When user clicks on the above mentioned link (that points to the store() method), it seems the browser simply jumps to the index (GET) of that controller and the code doesn't run because the store() method is bypassed.

When I move all code from within the store() method into the index() method, everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong here that my 'store()' method is not handling my code. Even when creating URL to the store action directly using URL::action, this fails.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Code:

Store method:

```
public function store()
    {
        $itemsArray = Session::get('sdata');

            $cartItem = new Cart;

            $cartItem->session_id = Session::get('sid');
            $cartItem->items = json_encode($itemsArray);

            $cartItem->save();

    return Response::make('an item was added to carts', 200);      
}
```

View:
         `<a href="{{ URL::route('shop.cart.store') }}">Go</a>`

Same result for this view also:

```
     `<a href="{{ URL::action('RelevantController@store') }}">Go</a>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `<a>` tag, is able to send only GET request. Try to create a new method, for example addToCart, and then set new rout on routes.php

Comment: i have moved this functionality to a new method altogether to solve this issue.

turns out POST method is only used with forms and you can't use it with links as I had tried to. That can be done, but with JS, which is not what POST was designed to be.

EDIT: Just saw your response, Gabrielyan. I ended up doing exactly as you advised above, even before reading it - even my new method is called addToCart. Thanks!